# Why are some Borgia's standards shown in the map?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

In *Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood* there are some standards spread across the city.

I've noticed that in some cases some of these banners are shown in the map and other not (the most common).

What is the criteria?

Comment: standarts? You mean standards surely as in banners?

Comment: I'm not sure the english name because I'm playing in another language, but I think yes. There are like a sort of flags.

Comment: Yep. I wasn't quite sure as I haven't played AC games for a while, but it looks like CyberSkull's done the corrections for ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unlock the banner icons on the map if you buy a map.

But to show them on your map manually, when the banner was in view while you were playing, it'll be drawn on the map. So that means if you don't see the banner around the corner, it's not on the map. As soon as you look around the corner, it's there. The same goes for further viewing, for example when you are on an eagle point. You may not see them yourselves but in the distance, there may be a visible banner. The game detects nothing obstructs your view and therefore draws the object on the map.

The same goes for most collectibles.